# Data with special characters is not displaying properly in jsp

Tags: java, jsp, utf-8, special-characters, iso-8859-1

Below are my application's oracle database characters settings.

[image]

There are some jobs running in the background to sync data from another application to my application.

Once I open the application, the data which is coming from another application is not displaying properly.

[image]

There are some special characters are coming with the data. So to avoid these special characters, I placed the encoding at JSP page level to UTF-8.

[image]

Now the data is displaying properly.

[image]

Everything is working fine. Now when I try to add the data from my application, which is having some Swedish characters, then those characters are not displaying properly.

[image]

So now I changed the encoding from UTF-8 to ISO-8859-1. Now the data which was entered from my application was displaying properly, but the data which was coming from another application is not displaying properly. I have checked my URIencoding at Apache Tomcat's server.xml and it is pointing to UTF-8 only.

[image]

Also I added the below code in Controller servlet from which every jsp page is displayed.

```
request.setCharcterEncoding("UTF-8");
response.setCharcterEncoding("UTF-8");
```

But still now UTF-8 encoding is working only for the data which is synch/coming from another application. This is not working for the data which is entering from my application.

Comment: How exactly is your application getting data from the database? Are you handling character sets correctly in your app? Note that some methods such as `new String(byte[])` use the default char encoding of your system which might not be UTF-8.

Comment: we are using internal api to get the data from the database. And also I have added encoding explicitely like new String(var.getBytes(), Charset.forName("UTF-8")); Then also I am getting ???? instead of original characters.

Comment: Too late to comment, however, did you get this resolved by any chance and if you recollect?